# Use formula across embedded excel sheets in MS Word (Office 365)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-word, office365

I have an excel sheet embedded in an MS-Word document. At another place in same document I want to put in some outcomes from the embedded spreadsheet (2 cells in particular). The word file needs to be shareable too.

I have tried "linking" excel sheet, but then have to share it (the excel) along with the docx file. Also tried embedding different spreadsheet, but the formulas in the sheets do not talk (or cannot talk to my knowledge)

Is there any way to do this in easy fashion?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible. The only workarounds would be to use:
a) an external Excel workbook, with each of your embedded worksheets linked to that; or
b) a macro to activate a given 'source' embedded worksheet in the document, gather the required data from there, then insert that data in the corresponding 'target' worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it  once